# In Sympy be, why does get_field fail for the finite field GF(9) (defined as a finite extension of GF(3))?

Tags: field, sympy

I'm trying to use the groebner function in Sympy to solve a system of multivariate polynomials in GF(9) = GF(3)[g]/(g**2 + 1). When I do this I get the error

> File
> "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/sympy/polys/groebnertools.py",
> line 37, in groebner
> orig, ring = ring, ring.clone(domain=domain.get_field())
>
> File
> "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/sympy/polys/domains/domain.py",
> line 846, in get_field
> raise DomainError('there is no field associated with %s' % self)
>
> DomainError: there is no field associated with GF(3)[g]/(g**2 + 1)

I reduced the code to the minimum that gives this get_field() failure. I also looked at is_field ... which was True!?
I know that GF and similar mechanisms fail for non-prime finite fields, but I thought that all would be well, if I defined my own GF(9) using a finite extension.
Am I missing something, or does get_field() not realize that gf9 is a field?

My minimal code

```
from sympy import Symbol, Poly
from sympy.polys.agca.extensions import FiniteExtension


g = Symbol('g')
gf9 = FiniteExtension(Poly(g**2 + 1, g, modulus=3))  # correct GF(9)
print('gf9 = ', gf9, 'type =', type(gf9), 'is_field?', gf9.is_Field)
print()
print('field associated with', gf9, '=', gf9.get_field())
```

Response

> gf9 =  GF(3)[g]/(g**2 + 1) is_field? True
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py",
> line 356, in compat_exec
> exec(code, globals, locals)
>
> File "/Users/rick/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 17, in 
> print('field associated with', gf9, '=', gf9.get_field())
>
> File
> "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9/sympy/polys/domains/domain.py",
> line 846, in get_field
> raise DomainError('there is no field associated with %s' % self)
>
> DomainError: there is no field associated with GF(3)[g]/(g**2 + 1)

Any help appreciated :)

Addendum: I just noticed that I never asked my real question: How can I use Sympy's groebner function with GF(3)[g]/(g**2 + 1)?

Comment: simpy is not sympy.  simpy is a discrete simulation package..  You might get more help with a different tag

Comment: @Michael Thanks, I hadn‘t noticed the mistake. I changed the tag.